# Angular2 not refreshing parent after deleting child

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

Recently I've made an example app with some features like: adding posts, adding comments to those posts, displaying list of posts.
Now I want add a delete post method.

My issue is that after deleting post and getting back to post list, the post list isn't refreshed. The deleted post is still there.

I've added method `renavigate` for refresh the page, but this thing is loading so long! It's like 1-2s to view the list.

How to view the refreshed component without invoked refreshing manually by `renavigate`?

My button in component template - `/blog` is a list of posts component:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/blog']" routerLinkActive="active"
           (click)="remove(blog.id); renavigate();"
           class="btn btn-1 btn-1e">Delete Post</a>
```

Rest of component's template:

```
<div *ngIf="isLoading">
    Loading&hellip;
</div>

<div *ngIf="error">
    Something went wrong!
</div>

<article *ngIf="blog" class="post">
    <header>
        <h2>{{ blog.id }}\ {{ blog?.title }}</h2>
    </header>
    <section class="article__content">
        {{ blog?.text }}
        <p class="author"> {{ blog?.name }}</p>
    </section>
    <footer>
        <a [routerLink]="['/blog']" routerLinkActive="active" class="btn btn-1 btn-1e">Return</a>
        <a [routerLink]="['/blog']" routerLinkActive="active"
           (click)="remove(blog.id);"
           class="btn btn-1 btn-1e">Delete Post</a>

    </footer>

    <my-comment [blogId]="blog.id"></my-comment>
    </article>
```

Remove in component:

```
remove(id: number): void {
        console.log(id);
        this.blogService.delete(id)
    }
```

Service delete function:

```
 public delete(id: number): Promise<void> {
        const url = `http://localhost:3000/posts/${id}`;
        return this.http.delete(url, {headers: this.headers})
            .toPromise()
            .then(() => null)
    }
```

The post-list component's template:

```
 <article *ngFor="let post of blogPosts">
        <div>
        <p>{{ post.id}}</p>
    <h2 class="cl-effect-21"><a [routerLink]="['/posts', post.id]">
        {{ post.title }}</a></h2>
            </div>
        <div class="border">
    <h5 class="date">[{{ post.date }}]</h5>, <h4>{{ post.name }}</h4>
            </div>
    </article>
```

Edited:
I realise the issue is with Chrome http cache. On Firefox the post is deleted after returned to post-list component page. Chrome doesn't fetch the new http request and displayed "old" post-list. Page have to be refreshed to see updated post-list component.

How to fixed this issue in Angular?

Comment: Could you add your component html code ?

Comment: why don't you get a result from your delete...and then in the promise call the routing to oher?

Comment: doesnt look like you  delete the post client side

Comment: I've added the rest of component template.
@federicoscamuzzi This is my first Angular2 app. I find that method in docs. How to call routing in the promise?

Comment: I don't see the relevant bit, where you use your list of posts that should be missing the deleted post.  Where does that come from and how do you use it?  If you show a list of posts and you don't alter that list on the client, you can't expect it to be gone.

Comment: @JasonGoemaat I added the parent component (post list).
The delete button is **inside** the child - in post template. In the same button is routing to parent. Parent should fetch the data from api and display the post-list without the deleted one. But It doesn't do that.

Comment: So you need to update the `blogPosts` array in the parent.  One way would be to have your child component just emit a `delete()` output and handle that on the parent, then reload thge list on the parent or just remove the deleted item from `blogPosts` after the api call succeeds.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is you "renavigate" before call your DELETE request.

You may add the "renavigate" after your promise in your "remove" method  :

```
remove(id: number): void {
    this.blogService.delete(id).then(() => this.renavigate());
}
```

And then modify your service as the following :

```
public delete(id: number): Promise<Response> {
    const url = `http://localhost:3000/posts/${id}`;
    return this.http.delete(url, {headers: this.headers})
        .toPromise())
}
```

Comment: Oh, sorry, I've added the rest of template. The post-list is a parent of current component. There is no iteration, delete is inside the component and I want to go 'up' to parent component and see the refreshed list without the deleted one (as I see now without 'renavigate' function).

Comment: It trows an error: `Property 'splice' does not exist on type 'BlogComponent'.`

Comment: And I don't have an array of posts, only the component to display the list of it.

Comment: OK the list is a subscription with results of something like http.get... ? So you have two options : 1- you cache the result and delete the item from the cache *BEFORE* the DELETE request ; 2- you do the subscription (the "renavigate" in your case) *AFTER*  the DELETE request (so where you wrote `.then(() => null)`)

Comment: I realise the issue is appeared only on Chrome. It doesn't refresh page so there is no http.get when app get back to post-list.
I want to avoid refresh the page manually and I can't delete item from list before delete request, because there is no list on page with "delete" button.

Comment: If your http.get subscripiton is in your parent component initialization (ngOnInit() method for best practice), you will referesh the posts list at any time you reload the component. Note if you use angular router, you won't have to reload your app.

Comment: But the problem is, it does not refresh automatically :) And only in Chrome.

Comment: I guess it's because Chrome use cache when you reload all your app. But there are solution to reload just a component. Did you try the edited above ?

Comment: The point is I don't want to use `renavigate()` at all. It's only because the page doesn't reload automatically because of Chrome cache feature.
And removing the `.then(()...` as you did above trows error: `Error:(33, 16) TS2322:Type 'Promise<Response>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<void>'.
  Type 'Response' is not assignable to type 'void'.`

I think putting a routing link to promise not in anchor link will solve the problem. But I don't know how to write that.

Comment: Sorry I miss that. I edited it again. For your "anchor" problem, you have to use Angular Router. Shortly you will add something like `RouterModule.forRoot([{ path: 'post', component: ParentComponent}, { path: 'post/:postId', component: PostDetailComponent }})` in your app.module.ts and a routerOutlet in you main component. Here is a working example : http://embed.plnkr.co/smUy1twVS8v5YBdDa0c9/ (see hero and heroDetails) and here is the complete documentation : https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

Comment: I've already have a routing in my app. See in code above.
The problem is that Chrome doesn't refresh cache on http request. I try to find another method, like add outing in promise.

Comment: To prevent Chrome caching your request you could add a dummy parameter that changes any time. See: `http://localhost:3000/posts?preventCache=${new Date()}`